# Format well-known/identity-configuration (Json) Response

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Anyone know how to format the Response from /well-known/identity-configuration with IdentityServer4?

Currently All Api Responses is nicely formatted with below config in startup.
How can I make this count for IdentityServer aswell?

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        // Catches all responses expect id-server..
        options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    });

services
    .AddIdentityServer(options => {
        // ToDo: Format Response
    }
```

I have looked on the options object like above but could not see any soultion here.. Anyone knows?

Comment: The short answer is no, not really - this isn't something that's configurable.

Comment: The formatting is coming from here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Infrastructure/ObjectSerializer.cs#L13 so unfortunatly, there's no easy way to achieve that.

Comment: that would be a nice feature request on github